# python failed to import cv2 (OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv

when I try to import cv on python3.6.8,it tracebacked:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

my opencv-python version is 4.1.0.25

Comment: `apt install -y libsm6` run this to install this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to install `libsm6` package.

Below is the command to do so.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple question, but I am not familiar with Ubuntu,the solution is install libSM.so.6.